# How to enumerate through multiple certificates in a bundle?

Tags: ruby, ssl-certificate, x509

I can create `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate` objects from files containing certificates:

```ruby
blob = IO.binread path
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new blob
```

However, this creates the certificate-object from *the first* certificate found in the file. When dealing with certificate-*bundles* the subsequent certificates in the same file are quietly ignored.

I suppose, I can split the `blob` on `"\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"` and feed each part to `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new`, but I'm not sure, that will work with all file-formats, that my script might encounter and be expected to operate on.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so with the assumption that only PEM-encoded certificates can be packed into a bundle, I wrote my code as below. If the assumption is invalid -- or if you can offer a better way, please let me know!

```
DELIMITER = "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
blob = IO.binread path
blobs = blob.split(DELIMITER)
blobs.each do |blob|
    blob += DELIMITER # Does not break DER
    cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new blob
    .... process the cert ....
end
```

Instead of splitting and then re-adding the delimiter, one could use `scan`, but that requires regular-expression use, which is probably more expensive, than what I'm doing...

This code works with DER-encoded certificates too -- but only one per file, because there is no obvious way to split them.

Comment: In a similar style, this is how the mongo ruby driver currently parses multiple CAs: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/commit/1f64d64172e38c302056f0108f0a32290d24897e#diff-ed625ecdabf4aeff5d1a5fc04b958a3aR184

Answer (score 3):

Did some digging, it seems that the Ruby openssl bindings doesn't support this. It also seems like this is not something that is common and/or easy to do with the raw C bindings. All the code I could find online shows doing stuff with a single cert, or using a X509 store to verify other certs. I've not seen any examples of having a single cert "object" refer to multiple certs, and/or iterating the certs in a store.

So I think the short answer is: no. At least nothing provided by the Ruby bindings can help you do this.

If your use case is to verify a certificate against a bundle of certificates, there's always `OpenSSL::X509::Store`, which has a method `store.add_file` that adds all the certs in that file to the store, and has methods to verify whether or not a cert is valid based on the bundle contents.

Comment: Thanks! What I need for _this_ application is check the expiration of all certificates in a file -- and report the earliest expiration found. Can I add add files -- with bundles and/or single certificates -- to a store? Can I then go through `store.each`?

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no enumeration of the items in a store. Seems like this goes all the way down to the C library, so Ruby is not at fault there. Is it possible for you to somehow get a folder of certificate files, instead of all the certificates in a single file?

Comment: _C library, so Ruby is not at fault there_ -- right, because Ruby is just a thin wrapper around C ;-)

Comment: It is, actually - the OpenSSL bindings in Ruby is just a thin OO wrapper :)

Comment: Actually with the C API you would use PEM_read_bio_X509(3ssl) in a loop, checking the return code and possibly BIO_eof(3ssl). That would read the whole bundle without any splitting.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about ruby, but with C you can load a CRT (and CRL) bundle like

```c
X509_STORE  *store = X509_STORE_new();
X509_LOOKUP *lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(store, X509_LOOKUP_file());

X509_LOOKUP_load_file(lookup, argv[i], X509_LU_X509);
```

and iterate over its elements with

```c
for (int i = 0; i < sk_X509_OBJECT_num(store->objs); ++i) {
    X509_OBJECT *o = sk_X509_OBJECT_value(store->objs, i);

    switch (o->type) {
    case X509_LU_X509:
        handle_crt(o->data.x509);
```